# what meta i need to set to let line app get my thumnail image when share website?

Tags: html, meta-tags

Example , facebook depend on meta info:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{$heading}}"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="{{$tip_info}}"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{{Config::get('facebook.app_id')}}" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="{{$url}}"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{$photoLink}}"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="vivo"/>
```

But in line app (http://line.me/en/), when i share link website, it only parse text and not receive any thumbnail image althougt website have many image.

Comment: It's Line's problem, isn't it?

Comment: But it still have website that line app can parse imagethumb, i don't know how they can do it. So i must ask on there

Comment: Maybe check the meta-tags of the websites that are showing up in their app, or ask them? The SO community doesn't own Line, nor have they developed it.

Answer (score 4):

They use Facebook Open Graph

```
<meta property=”og:image” content=”http://static.naver.jp/line_lp/img/ogp.png”>
<meta property=”og:title” content=”LINE : Free Calls & Messages”>
<meta property=”og:description” content=”LINE is a new communication app”>
```

Search for `How are the URL previews in chats and on Timeline generated?`
on the Line Faq link: https://developers.line.me/en/faq/
and refer to this [blog article](http://www.language-diary.com/2018/03/what-meta-tags-do-kakaotalk-and-line.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I send the structure of the meta tag:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
<meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

just want to make people who see here note:
the content of `og:image`, which is the url, must need to be static, that means

start with

```
https://.......
```

not

```
/......
```

since the crawler of the SNS will not know where you save the thumbnail